# For .vue file phpstorm code collapse or folding is not visible between <script>

Tags: vue.js

In phpstorm there is no folding +/- between script tag for .vue file using vue-for-idea. Therefore arrays and closures won't fold. This does work as expected in sublime

So there is no folding for export default or mounted:

```
<script> export default { mounted() { console.log('Component ready.') } } </script>
```

I have done the routine install/unistall resart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in vue-for-idea plugin. You should post an issue in it's repository or if it yourself and post a pull request. Here is the repository URL: https://github.com/henjue/vue-for-idea

As for how to solve the issue, I just use another vue plugin called Vue.js. Here is the repository for this plugin: https://github.com/postalservice14/vuejs-plugin.